# getting result after passing stmt to another function

Tags: php, function, pdo

In the below code.  I can not get checkForResult to return anything.  I would expect either a 0 or the value of $r['id'].  When i echo $myResult, there is no result, not null, no blank, nothin...What am I missing?

```
$myResult = getId($db,someField,someValue);



function checkForResult($stmt){
    if ($stmt->rowCount() < 1){
       return 0;
    }else{
       while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
          return $r['id'];
       }
    }
}

function getId($db,$field,$value){
     $sel = "SELECT id from table where field='".$field."' and value='".$value."'";
     $stmt = $db->query($sel);
     checkForResult($stmt);
}
```

Comment: Your function `getId` doesn't return anything so `$myResult` will be blank.

Comment: doesnt checkForResult() do the work of returning something?

Comment: It only passes the value back to the caller, you need to pass the value back up - `return checkForResult($stmt);`

Comment: Regarding `rowCount`, from [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php): "If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed for all databases and should not be relied on for portable applications."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function `checkForResult` returns value, but it only does it in the previous scope, which is your method `getId`. To return the value from `getId` you also need to add `return`. Like this:

```
function getId($db, $field, $value)
{
    $sel  = "SELECT id from table where field=? and value=?";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sel);
    $stmt->execute([$field, $value]);
    return checkForResult($stmt);
}
```